# What's the difference between argp and getopt?

Tags: c, arguments, gnu, getopt, argp

I think the title is self explanatory. I am making a program and I was wondering what I should use of the two and why.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Argp.html explains well

Comment: @lostyzd updating link: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html#Argp . Curiosity: argp [is based on getopts](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=argp/argp.h;h=40bf5e6b631e06a14a5416a82d1a589593858336;hb=4e42b5b8f89f0e288e68be7ad70f9525aebc2cff#l1).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`argp` may be more flexible / powerful / etc, but `getopt` is part of the POSIX standard. Thats a choice you've to make based on whether you expect your program to be portable.

Comment: What does it mean for `getopt` to be more portable? Won't they both run everywhere?

Answer (score 4):

From the [Argp manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Argp.html):

> Argp provides features unavailable in the more commonly used getopt
>   interface. These features include automatically producing output in
>   response to the ‘--help’ and ‘--version’ options, as described in the
>   GNU coding standards. Using argp makes it less likely that programmers
>   will neglect to implement these additional options or keep them up to
>   date.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much to choose I don't think.  The [Argp webpage](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html) says this:

> Argp provides features unavailable in the more commonly used getopt
>   interface. These features include automatically producing output in
>   response to the ‘--help’ and ‘--version’ options, as described in the
>   GNU coding standards. Using argp makes it less likely that programmers
>   will neglect to implement these additional options or keep them up to
>   date.
>
> Argp also provides the ability to merge several independently defined
>   option parsers into one, mediating conflicts between them and making
>   the result appear seamless. A library can export an argp option parser
>   that user programs might employ in conjunction with their own option
>   parsers, resulting in less work for the user programs. Some programs
>   may use only argument parsers exported by libraries, thereby achieving
>   consistent and efficient option-parsing for abstractions implemented
>   by the libraries.